# Jquery AJAX with ASP.NET WebMethod refreshing the entire page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, ajax

I am using Jquery Ajax to set the values of a Label and a ListBox in my form.  I realize that values are set properly by the function. But just after that , the page just refreshes clearing all previously set values . Why is this happening ? Iam new to Jquery/Ajax. Am I missing any fundamentals here ?   Thanks in Advance.

Iam pasting the entire code

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Button1').bind('click', function clk() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "WebForm5.aspx/TestMethod",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert(result.d.ListBox.length);
                        for (var i = 0; i < result.d.ListBox.length; i++) {
                            alert(result.d.ListBox[i]);
                            $(document.createElement("option")).attr("value", result.d.ListBox[i]).html(result.d.ListBox[i])
   .appendTo('#<%=ListBox1.ClientID  %>');

                            $('#Label1').text(result.d.MyProperty);
                        }
                    }
                });
            })
        });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Button1` in your code is an asp button which is a submit button. When you click on it, it will submit the page and refresh the whole page. If you want to stop the page from being submitted on button click `return false`, it will work.

```
$('#Button1').bind('click', function clk() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "WebForm5.aspx/TestMethod",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert(result.d.ListBox.length);
                        for (var i = 0; i < result.d.ListBox.length; i++) {
                            alert(result.d.ListBox[i]);
                            $(document.createElement("option")).attr("value", result.d.ListBox[i]).html(result.d.ListBox[i])
   .appendTo('#<%=ListBox1.ClientID  %>');

                            $('#Label1').text(result.d.MyProperty);
                        }
                    }
                });

  return false;
            })
```

Comment: ..Thanks ..Works perfectly..Could you please enlighten me why this happened and how "return false" did the trick ?

Comment: Added the explaination in my answer take a look.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was looking all over as to why my button was auto refreshing. I added the return false and it works exactly as expected.